# Memory Access Error- Vector Resize

Tags: c++, vector

I have two columns of size N1 and N2. Both the sizes are more than 1 billion. Now i want to define a vector and resize its size to N1 X N2.

I tried to implement this using the vector resize function as below but got a memory access error. Are there any other way to achieve this.

```
    myvector.resize(N1*N2);
```

Thanks for suggestions

Comment: Assuming a vector of `int` (4 bytes), 1 billion by 1 billion, as a quick approximation is 4000 Petabytes or 4000000000 GB. That's a big vector.

Comment: @Borgleader Only amateurs *buy* RAM, real programmers just [download more RAM](http://www.downloadmoreram.com/)!

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have to store all items in memory? You should check if you can operate with smaller blocks of the matrix ( if you have one ).
For such big operations like the descriped one storing all items in memory will scale not very well. What I have done: get a block, operate on it and write it back into your medium. This will avoid the out-of-memory errror.

Please check this side about out-of-core algorithms to learn more about the ideas behind this approach: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-core_algorithm

Comment: Even with this approach of pulling from disk to memory and vice versa, they're still WAY beyond the amount of space they'll have on disk (if you look at my comment above). They might be able to get away with sparse array linear algebra algorithms if they do it carefully.

Comment: Right, but giving an idea how to deal with stuff like this is also a beginning to understand where the problem lies.